# excel online and confused in conditional formatting

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, excel-online

I am using excel online and confused in conditional formatting that it has just few colors for formatting.

I have tried to find online to use different colors for formatting but could not find any article.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel Online is a limited Excel version that is build just for increasing processing power. Therefore, one of the changes applied is for color palettes. For now options are limited.

Comment: Thnaks i understand